# Can I use an svg markup element (g) as a root element of a React JSX return value?

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, jsx

I would like to do this:

#### Component `Client / Child`

```
return (
            <Limage>
              <g id="golf">
                <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M26.007885,46.7037048 c0,0-10.666666-20.6913586,2.6666679-28.8888893c0,0-11.6543217-0.2962971-14.5185194-10.8148155 c0,0-2.3703699,4.4938269,2.5185194,10.0740738C16.6745529,17.0740738,10.6992435,31.1481476,26.007885,46.7037048z"/>
                <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M15.7856636,33.9629631 l-1.4814816-5.6296291c0,0-6.0740747,7.3580227-4.1481485,18.666666C10.1560335,47,10.4029474,39.0493813,15.7856636,33.9629631z" />
                <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14.1560335,7L36,1l3,4 l-0.0000038,0.000001c-1.1943779,0.5971899-2.6368942,0.3631015-3.5811348-0.5811381L33,2"/>
                <circle fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="26" cy="10" r="4"/>
                <line fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="17" y1="45" x2="17" y2="48"/>
                <circle fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="17" cy="43" r="4"/>
              </g>
            </Limage>
)
```

#### Component `Parent`

```
componentDidMount () {

  this.runOnClientSide((v) => {
    this.state.vivus = new v(this.props.name)
  })

}

render () {
  return (
    <svg id={this.props.name}>
      {this.props.children}
    </svg>
  )
}
```

What seems to happen fairly consistently, though, is this:

```
<svg id="whatever"></svg>
```

In other words, **nothing shows up in the SVG!**

Is this a limitation of `React` and trying to use the `g` element as a `JSX` wrapper element? Is there an easy workaround if so?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to delete this but I thought it was worth mentioning if you happen to be using `Vivus`.

I was setting something in my `state` upon `componentDidMount`, which led to a different `id` because I was using an `id` that was dynamic, which led to a `render`, but without another call to `Vivus`, which meant no animation and a warning about differing `id`.

The point: if you are going to use `Vivus`, follow these guidelines:

1. Make a wrapper. Mine is shared here.
2. In the wrapper, use `componentDidMount` to call `Vivus`
3. **Get `Vivus` using `require` rather than `import`. ** I cannot stress this enough as this is a client-side *only* affair!
4. **Make sure you are not setting state immediately after rendering!** This is often a bad sign, anyway.

#### My wrapper

Your mileage *will* vary because this kind of sucks... you should only use it as a starter or a guide, and extend it as you need.

```
export class Limage extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    duration: React.PropTypes.number
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    name: new Date().getTime().toString(),
    duration: 2000
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  runOnClientSide (what) {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      if (null == this.Vivus) {
        this.Vivus = require('vivus')
      }

      what(this.Vivus)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {

    this.runOnClientSide((v) => {

      window.x = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.svgMarkup)

      this.vivus = new v(this.props.name, {
        duration: 20000
      })
    })

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <svg id={this.props.name} ref='svgMarkup'>{this.props.children}</svg>
    )
  }

}

export default Limage
```

#### My example

```
export class Header extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <Navigation className={s.nav} />
          <Link className={s.brand} to="/">
            <Limage>
              <g id="golf">
                <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="4" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M26.007885,46.7037048 c0,0-10.666666-20.6913586,2.6666679-28.8888893c0,0-11.6543217-0.2962971-14.5185194-10.8148155 c0,0-2.3703699,4.4938269,2.5185194,10.0740738C16.6745529,17.0740738,10.6992435,31.1481476,26.007885,46.7037048z"/>
                <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="4" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M15.7856636,33.9629631 l-1.4814816-5.6296291c0,0-6.0740747,7.3580227-4.1481485,18.666666C10.1560335,47,10.4029474,39.0493813,15.7856636,33.9629631z" />
                <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="4" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M14.1560335,7L36,1l3,4 l-0.0000038,0.000001c-1.1943779,0.5971899-2.6368942,0.3631015-3.5811348-0.5811381L33,2"/>
                <circle fill="none" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="4" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" cx="26" cy="10" r="4"/>
                <line fill="none" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="4" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" x1="17" y1="45" x2="17" y2="48"/>
                <circle fill="none" stroke="#fff" strokeWidth="4" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" cx="17" cy="43" r="4"/>
              </g>
            </Limage>
            <span className={s.brandTxt}>tacos_cubed</span>
          </Link>
          <div className={s.banner}>
            <h1 className={s.bannerTitle}>React</h1>
            <p className={s.bannerDesc}>Complex web apps made easy</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```